# nVidia GTX 1080 Ti support for 3 4k monitors

Tags: nvidia-graphics-card, 4k-resolution

Will it be possible to use the GTX 1080 Ti as a GPU for three 27 inch 4k monitors, assuming that the main purpose of the PC is programming?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible.

Bought three 27 inch 4k displays, plugged them into the 1080Ti, had a laggy experience which is not even suitable for programming.

Answer (score 1):

Can't speak to gaming, but 3 x 4K@60hz works fine with my 1060 6GB for programming. No different than a single screen.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible for this marvelous video card, and much more.

For a hardware test report see the article
[NVIDIA's GeForce GTX 1080 GPU benchmarked at Triple 4K (11,520 x 2160)](https://www.tweaktown.com/articles/7708/nvidias-geforce-gtx-1080-gpu-benchmarked-triple-4k-11-520-2160/index2.html).

In the Heaven is an intensive GPU benchmark,
it hit 10.7 FPS on average.

The conclusions says:

> Does the performance live up to what we expected? Yes, it does. The GTX 1080 beats every other card we tested in every single test, which is a huge win for NVIDIA. We have a card that handles 11,520 x 2160 better than the $999 Titan X, and the HBM1-powered Radeon R9 Fury X.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! 10.7 average FPS seems a bit rough even for programming isn't it?

Comment: On all three monitors at once it's not bad. One monitor will certainly do much better.